# Is it possible to install an app from Google Chrome Web Store like Angry Birds so that it is available to all users?

Tags: 10.04, google-chrome, webapps

I use Google Chrome at home and recently I installed AngryBirds from the webstore but to my surprise it wasn't available on my wife's account. Is it possible to install Chrome apps such that they are available on all user accounts on the system and doesn't require installing for individual users. This will save some disk space and help me save time by not installing every app twice.

**Update**:
I am not talking about app shortcuts that we can create with chrome. I am talking about Chrome Apps which can be installed from Chrome Web Store https://chrome.google.com/webstore?hl=en-US e.g Angry Birds, Pacman and others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome Apps (not shortcuts) are stored in the Google Chrome Profile. The debian version (even beta/unstable) do not yet featured multiple shared/synced profiles, however they do feature singular synchronization.

In simpler terms, your personal stuff is in your home folder, and while other users may be able to get to it, chrome will run from their profile in their folder.

You can either:

**How to Sync Apps across User**

`Settings` > `Sign In`
or
Sign In at the top-right of the new tab page.

You can select what data to synchronise, so you could just select apps.
Then login to that sync account on all users.

#### Add Launchers/Shortcuts with Special Parameters

Move the Profile into a public place.
Edit the Launcher/Shortcut on all Users and append --user-data-dir="/public/place/"

#### Alternative

For a large number of users you can make a script, but this is something you'd have to research yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A Chrome app is essentially just a shortcut. This makes it easy to install them for all users.

To do this, simply copy the .desktop file (launcher) from your account to `/usr/share/applications`.
For the easy way:

- run `gksu nautilus /usr/share/applications`, then copy and paste the conventional way.

For the hard way (if you are not command line savvy):

- `sudo cp /path/to/file /usr/share/applications/`.

It is also possible to have an automatic method. Create folder somewhere in /usr/share or in some other shared location. Give it write permissions for everyone. Then symlink this folder to your user accounts. When you install Chrome webapps, simply drop the launcher in that folder.

Comment: I am not talking about app shortcuts that we can create from Chrome. I am talking about Chrome apps that get installed from the Chrome Web Store i.e https://chrome.google.com/webstore?hl=en-US I am sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @binW... oh. That's um... rather different.